# Rails execute script on server on Dojo Button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dojo, jrubyonrails

I've ruby script as part of rails application which is used to copy files from some directory to another inside the server. I am using Dojo as front-end. I've a dojo widget which is displaying a button fine. Now I want to the script to be executed when I click the Dojo button.

Wigdet extract:

```
<input type="button" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" dojoAttachEvent="_onClick:copyfiles" label="Copy Files"></input>
```

JavaScript function part of widget:

```
copyfiles: function() {
window.location = '/files/copy_files'
}
```

in routes I have:

```
resources :files do
get :copy_files
```

and in files_controller I have:

```
def copy_files
  fc = FilesCopier.new
  source = '/home/myname/sourcefiles'
  dest = '/home/myname/backup'
  fc.copy_files(source,dest)
end
```

But when I clicked the button nothing happens. I've also tried running the code inside a view but nothing happens.

Comment: Do any JS errors pop up in your dev console? What does your Rails log tel you, is the route being hit?

Comment: I don't get any error. Path is actually loaded http/1.1 OK so no problem there.

Comment: Does your copy_files method work, if you call it for example directly in your console?

Comment: The method works perfect. Now even If i put it on the main page it will be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved it. 
All I have to do was to change the routes file as per below:

```
put :copy_files, :on => :collection
```

And now even if I put it on show method inside the controller it will work.